# C Program random value

Tags: c

Hey I'm trying to generate a random value between the min and max in C where the first parameter of the function represents the maximum value and the minimum value is the previous maximum value from the previous call. The function works but for some reason the values generated seem to always end in the same digit.

```
void myRand(int max, int* randValue)
{
    static int newMin = 0;

    srand(time(NULL));

    *randValue = (newMin)+rand()%((max-newMin)+1); /* produces random value between previous max value and new max value in parameter 1 */

    newMin = max;
}

int main(void)
{
    int a, b;

    myRand(10, &a);
    printf("%d\n", a);

    myRand(20, &b);
    printf("%d\n", b);

    myRand(30, &b);
    printf("%d\n", b);

    return 0;
}
```

In the first call of the function the minimum is 0.

Comment: Call `srand(time(NULL));` just **once**.

Comment: Yeah fixed the problem, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `srand(time(NULL))` just once. So move the `srand` in the start of `main`.